# How do I convert a text string to an int in C to find parts in it?

Tags: c, string, variables, int, cs50

My current issue with this code has to do with the Punctuation Count if statement `if(Text == '.' || Text == '!' || Text == '?')`.

Is there a variable I can create to replace `Text` in this situation and allow the code to run its process?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{  //Letter Count Section
string Text = get_string("Text: "); //Gets Text
char Checker = isalpha(Text); // Checks for letters
int Count = strlen(&Checker); //Counts letters

//Space Count Section
 int Spaces = 0; //Declares Variable
if(isspace(Text)){ //Checks for Spaces
 Spaces += 1; //Adds +1 to Variable if Space
}

//Punctuation Count
 if(Text == '.' || Text == '!' || Text == '?')
 Punctuation += 1;

float Sentence = (Count/(Spaces*100));
float Letters = (Punctuation/(Spaces*100));
 printf("\n%f",Sentence);
 printf("\n%f",Letters);

 // Formula  
    int gradelvl = (0.0588 * Letters - 0.296 * Sentence - 15.8);
 // End Result  
        printf("\nGradelevel: %i\n",gradelvl);
}
```

Comment: You should be using `Text[i]` instead of `Text` to check individual characters.

Comment: @Ardent Coder - At the get string function? Sorry I'm a bit new to C and arrays in general.

Comment: I mean, most parts of your code should have been inside a loop. For example, `for (size_t i = 0; i < /*length of text*/; ++i) if (isspace(text[i])) ++spaces;`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However what would I use to show length of text? Text[i]?

Comment: I don't know how `cs50.h` works. [This manual](https://man.cs50.io/3/strlen) says that our normal `strlen` can be used to find the length of `string`: `strlen(text)`.

Comment: cs50 is just a training tool I'm using at the moment. 

For the loop you suggested would that use be more so ```for (Text i = 0; i < Count; ++i)  if (isspace(text[i])) ++spaces;``` in my case?

Comment: No. `i` is the index of characters inside `string Text`, so it should be a natural number. In your proposition, you treat `i` as a `string` (`Text` is not even a datatype). That justifies the use of `size_t`. Coming to your `Count`, what exactly is `Count`? It is the length of the string: `strlen(Text)`. You may also want to refresh your knowledge on datatypes, for-loop, and arrays. I haven't gone through the logic of your code, feel free to ask if there are more errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a variable I can create to replace Text in this situation and allow the code to run its process?

```
  char c = Text[0];
```

Comment: Does this go below the string function or replace?

Answer (score 0):

A C string is basically just an array of `char` values. E.g. the following two definitions are both valid:

```
char * stringAsPtr = "Hello World";
char stringAsArray[] = "Hello World";
```

Thus you can process any string as an array:

```
for (size_t i = 0; stringAsArray[i]; i++) {
    char c = stringAsArray[i];
    // Do something with c, e.g. check if it is a space 
    // and increase your space counter if it is.
}
```

Note that `stringAsArray[i]` as a boolean expression is identical to `stringAsArray[i] != 0` and to `stringAsArray[i] != '\0'`, so the for loop will end once you hit the terminating NUL character of the C string.